# Is interruption also an asynchronous exception in GHC?

Tags: haskell, ghc

When trying to understand how GHC programs work with regard to signals and exceptions, I found an interesting if inconclusive discussion regarding ["fixing" the bracket](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2014-November/024351.html).

I struggle to understand why would a change be needed when a bracket already [masks asynchronous exceptions](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-13.16/base-4.12.0.0/src/Control-Exception-Base.html#bracket).

It seems to me that either interruption (as in POSIX signals) is not an asynchronous exception or I'm missing some detail in the current long-standing implementation:

```
bracket before after thing =
  mask $ \restore -> do
    a <- before
    r <- restore (thing a) `onException` after a
    _ <- after a -- can be interrupted??
    return r
```

In my understanding, `after a` must be evaluated to provide `IO` action that will be forced by `IO` monad which is within `mask` scope.

EDIT: While on the topic, how come `after` isn't run twice in case of an exception?

Comment: "how come after isn't run twice in case of an exception?" - `onException` doesn't _catch_ the exception

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`mask`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:mask) *sort of* prevents asynchronous interruptions from being raised.

> Asynchronous exceptions may still be received while in the masked state if the masked thread *blocks* in certain ways

There's a different function, [`uninterruptibleMask`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:uninterruptibleMask), which does completely block async exceptions.

A POSIX interrupt signal does by default result in an [`AsyncException`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#t:AsyncException) raised in the main thread. If I'm understanding correctly, I don't think that's relevant to your question. When people are saying "interruptable" they're not referring specifically to the POSIX interrupt signal; they mean that an action is "interruptable" if it has not been masked with `uninterruptibleMask` and therefore can receive any async exception from any source.